# Drupal 7 using jQuery API, code not working

Tags: jquery, drupal

Hi I'm writing a small amount of jQuery for a site to effect a fade() or a show() of replacement content over a Map. I have created div areas that are positioned relatively over each area of the map, what I want to effect is for the user to click on these div's and then the replacement image will fade in and then can be closed easily.

I have installed JS injector, jQuery Update set to 1.8, and have modified the jQuery code so it is Drupal friendly having done some research on that, however when clicking on the div's no effect / function is going anything.

I'm not that experienced with jQuery, hence struggling and need help, code below : 
(function ($) {

```
$('#maparea1').click(function () {
$('<img src ="sites/all/themes/west_midlands_fire_service/img/map1.png"/> ').fade();
});

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually tend to use "jQuery" instead of "$" because I find the wrapper function annoying and I have to look up how to do it each time.

Is it really that much worse to type:

```
jQuery('#maparea1').click(function () {
jQuery('<img src ="sites/all/themes/west_midlands_fire_service/img/map1.png"/> ').fade();
});
```

Actually, I would suggest that it is cleaner and easier to read, not to mention 2 lines shorter!